# How do I get the height of a tabcontainer using jQuery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, tabcontainer

I have a tabcontainer within an accordion.

If the tab I am on is shorter than the tab I switch to, I have to scroll to see the content on the new tab.

I want to be able to "catch" the height of the tabcontainer when I switch to it and resize the div that contains it.

I thought:

```
 function clientActiveTabChanged(sender, args) {

         alert(sender.height());
        };
```

would show me the height, but it doesn't work.

TabContainer is:

```
 <ajaxToolkit:TabContainer ID="projTabContainer" OnClientActiveTabChanged="clientActiveTabChanged"  runat="server" CssClass="ajax__tab_red-theme">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think that this will help you : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15372333/how-can-i-get-a-tabcontainer-id-using-jquery-or-javascript)

```
$(myJquerySelector).attr('id');
```

You have just to change the `"id"` to `"height"`

EDIT : You can get the target of the event using : [event_target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/)

And to pick the id :

```
 $('TabContainer').change(function(event) {
  var tabContainerID = $(event.target).attr('id');
  alert(tabContainerID);
});
```

And now you have the id when you click on the tab.
With this id you can find the height easily. 
I hope that this will help you.

Comment: Trouble is, I don't know the ID of the element, as the tabcontainer is nested in a repeater. is there a way I can use "sender" to identify the element?

Answer (score 1):

The `sender` passed to the `clientActiveTabChanged` is not a jQuery object, it is a DOMElement. Try the following:

```
function clientActiveTabChanged(sender, args) {
  var height = $(sender).height();
  console.log('height is: ' + height);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can auto re-size the tab container- *(Reference: [Auto Resize TabContainer](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25568/Auto-Resize-TabContainer))*

```
function clientActiveTabChanged() {
    //get the tabContainer for later reference
    var tc = document.getElementById("<%=tabContainer.ClientId%>");

    //get the index of the tab you just clicked.
    var tabIndex = 
         parseInt($find("<%=tabContainer.ClientId%>").get_activeTabIndex(), 10);

    //set the tabcontainer height to the tab panel height.
    tc.childNodes[1].style.height = 
         tc.childNodes[1].childNodes[tabIndex].clientHeight;
};
```

Make the changes in above function as required.